# Which one should I use: MySQL Lite or SQLite?

Tags: mysql, winforms, sqlite, installation, prerequisites

I am starting a simple windows forms application that requires a database to store inventory and purchasing records (less than 1000 items). What I want to ask is for your opinion which 'lite' database should I use for this small project, considering that the prerequisites I'll be installing in a client computer should have 'minimal' file size.

The client computer has a running OS of Windows 7, and I don't want him to install so many files, such as the .NET framework and the server that hosts the database, just to install the main application I'm currently developing.

What I'm really asking from you guys is to find out which of these two commonly known databases should I use, and look for the 'right recipe' to be used when building the installer. Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as MySQL Lite, and it's SQLite, not SQL Lite.

Comment: @BoltClock: stand corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the two, SQLite is simpler to install and deploy. Fewer files, smaller distribution footprint and fewer configuration options to deal with (mostly because SQLite is a library that links into your application where as MySQL is a full client/server RDBMS).

Comment: For a small single user system, as per the posts here, SQLite is much simpler to setup / manage - however MySQL is much better for larger systems - if there is any chance that this may grow beyond a few users / a few thousand records, then I'd recommend using an abstraction layer like PDO or DBX so its easier to migrate later.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is made for extremely simple database needs, and is probably a good fit based on your description.

I have never heard of MySQL Lite and a web search turned up nothing, so I will assume you meant MySQL.  MySQL is a RDBS client/server system and probably major overkill unless you plan to store many records, or to have multiple people accessing the database at the same time.

Comment: Ahh. What I'm trying to say is the MySQL database used by phpMyAdmin using WAMP/XAMPP. The one I didn't install the whole MySQL database server.

Comment: @eibhrum: You can't use MySQL without the server.